# Is it bad practice to bind a variable inside the Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

I believe this is bad practice, but can someone please confirm this? It is a set of variables inside a model object being populated on the get.

```
public List<SelectListItem> YearsAtAddressList
                {
                    get
                    {
                        List<SelectListItem> YearsAtAddressList = new List<SelectListItem>();
                        YearsAtAddressList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Please select...", Value = "Please select..." });
                        YearsAtAddressList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Less than 1 year", Value = "0" });
                        YearsAtAddressList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1", Value = "1" });
                        YearsAtAddressList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "2", Value = "2" });
                        YearsAtAddressList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "3", Value = "3" });
                        YearsAtAddressList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "4", Value = "4" });
                        YearsAtAddressList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "5", Value = "5" });
                        YearsAtAddressList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "6", Value = "6" });
                        YearsAtAddressList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "7", Value = "7" });
                        YearsAtAddressList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "8", Value = "8" });
                        YearsAtAddressList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "9", Value = "9" });
                        YearsAtAddressList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "10", Value = "10" });
                        YearsAtAddressList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "11", Value = "11" });
                        YearsAtAddressList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "12", Value = "12" });
                        YearsAtAddressList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "13", Value = "13" });
                        YearsAtAddressList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "14", Value = "14" });
                        YearsAtAddressList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "15", Value = "15" });
                        YearsAtAddressList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "16", Value = "16" });
                        return YearsAtAddressList;
                    }
                    private set { }
                }

                //DOB Days
                public List<SelectListItem> Days
                {
                    get
                    {
                        List<SelectListItem> Days = new List<SelectListItem>();
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "DD", Value = "DD" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1", Value = "1" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "2", Value = "2" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "3", Value = "3" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "4", Value = "4" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "5", Value = "5" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "6", Value = "6" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "7", Value = "7" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "8", Value = "8" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "9", Value = "9" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "10", Value = "10" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "11", Value = "11" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "12", Value = "12" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "13", Value = "13" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "14", Value = "14" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "15", Value = "15" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "16", Value = "16" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "17", Value = "17" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "18", Value = "18" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "19", Value = "19" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "20", Value = "20" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "21", Value = "21" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "22", Value = "22" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "23", Value = "23" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "24", Value = "24" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "25", Value = "25" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "26", Value = "26" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "27", Value = "27" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "28", Value = "28" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "29", Value = "29" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "30", Value = "30" });
                        Days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "31", Value = "31" });
                        return Days;
                    }
                    private set { }
                }
```

Comment: It's not bad practice, per se, just the way it's done here is. You should use a private field to store the value and then use your property getter to set that field if it's null and then return it. You should also just leave the setter out completely if you're not going to do anything with it.

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely a bad practice, because every time you call the getter of your property the whole collection is created once again. 
It is a better practice to create this list outside the scope of your get section and then just return the already populated list everytime the getter is called:

```
List<SelectListItem> _yearsAtAddressList = PopulateList();
public List<SelectListItem> YearsAtAddressList
{
    get
    {
        return _yearsAtAddressList;
    }
    private set { }
}
```

And then the PopulateList() method could look like this:

```
public List<SelectListItem> PopulateList()
{
    var yearsAtAddressList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    yearsAtAddressList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Please select...", Value = "Please select..." });
    yearsAtAddressList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = Less than 1 year", Value = "0" });
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        yearsAtAddressList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = i, Value = i });
    }
    return yearsAtAddressList;
}
```

Comment: To be really efficient, you could leave the global field empty until someone calls the getter, then check if it's null and populate it once. (Depends on the circumstances though... Are there cases where that particular getter is never called in an instance of that class? Does it hurt to populate it during creation of the class? etc. )

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same thing. Just move the `PopulateList` logic into the getter for `YearsAtAddressList` and only run it if `_yearsAtAddressList` is null.

Comment: @MrPaulch - I don't think getters should have any logic in them so I think the list should be populated once either in the ctor or in an initialization method

Comment: @vidalsasoon - Well tell me one good reason for getters not to have logic. One branch in a getter doesn't hurt that much. And if you care about performance on a cpu instruction level, then there is other concerns. And as i said, depending on your class design it might not be called for. But in some cases it might save you some memory allocation.

Comment: @MrPaulch Getter/Setter properties should be extremely fast. If it's a heavier operation maybe it should be moved to a method.

Comment: @vidalsasoon - Except for the first call the getter WILL be extreamly fast. There are pro's and con's to both variants, i'm doing an advocatus diaboli here. But i had at least one instance where using this method spared me a lot of refactoring. Without distrupting the general class design and flow. So i guess it shouldn't be unmentioned.